# JavaScript Alert not disappearing when ok is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, alert

I have created a JQuery dynamic table here and I'm trying to implement input checking to make sure only the numbers are saved. The cell is updated either by clicking outside of it or by pressing the enter button and what I am trying to achieve is having an alert whenever an invalid input is entered.

The 'focusout' function alert is is working perfectly. The 'keypress' function alert on the other hand is behaving strangely, the alert message is popping out as normal however it doesn't go away no matter how many times I click ok.

According to console.log() the alert is triggering the 'focusout' function somehow. But even if that was the case, I don't understand how that is causing the error since the 'focusout' function works fine. I've tried to use $(this).focus() after the alert but this didn't work. Any Idea what I may be missing?

Thanks in advance

```
$(document).on('keypress', '.row_data', function (event) {

  if (event.which === 13) {
    event.preventDefault()
    
    if (isNaN($(this).html())) {
      alert("Enter valid number")
    } else {
      var elem = $(this)
      saveValue(elem)
    }
  }
});

/* Saves the edited cell data when user clicks outside the cell */
$(document).on('focusout', '.row_data', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  if (isNaN($(this).html())) {
    alert("Enter valid number")
  } else {
    var elem = $(this)
    saveValue(elem)
  }
});
```

EDIT

So here is my HMTL for context. I am using Handlebars to create a table but basically all my cells are like this..

```
      <span class="row_data" edit_type="click" col_name="col_1">{{col_1}}</span>
    </td>
    <td>£
      <span class="row_data" edit_type="click" col_name="col_2">{{col_2}}</span>
    </td>
    <td>£
      <span class="row_data" edit_type="click" col_name="col_3">{{col_3}}</span>
    </td>
```

and I'm using JQuery to make the cells editable like this...

```
/* Makes each cell on the table editable */
$(document).on('click', '.row_data', function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  if ($(this).attr('edit_type') === 'button') {
    return false;
  }

  $(this).closest('span').attr('contenteditable', 'true');
  $(this).css("background-color", "beige").css('padding', '5px');
  $(this).focus();
})
```

Comment: _“it doesn't go away no matter how many times I click ok”_ - so then it likely is not one single alert that just “won’t go away”, but they are _separate_ alerts, only showing the same message each time. Assuming there are actual input fields involved here, you should consider using the `input` event instead of the two you are trying to use now, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event - that should avoid any issues you currently have with the field losing focus due to the alert, triggering another alert again.

Comment: Is `.row_data'` class of the input?

Comment: Your `alert` is triggering the `focusout` event, which... creates another alert.  Always use `console.log` rather than `alert` to alleviate side-effects like this.

Comment: Yeah .row_data is the class. Sorry I should have included my HTML for context

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made some changes below to your code and have commented on it fully. It's best to not repeat code whenever possible, and just maintain a single function and trigger that using various methods rather than having to ensure two different functions are maintained separately.

You are currently triggering your `alert` multiple times, we can rationalize the code a bit to avoid the two different functions triggering the warning.

I think you can simplify things by using:

```
$(":focus").blur();
```

This removes the focus from whichever element is in focus.

I've assumed your `.row_data` is an `input`, so have also used `.val()` rather than `.html()`, you might need to change this back depending on your use case.

Let me know if you were hoping for something else.

---

```js
// I would recommend using keyup rather than keypress
$(document).on('keyup', '.row_data', function(event) {

  // Check if it is a return
  if (event.which === 13) {

    // Remove focus
    // This will triger the function below, it'll be easier to manage a single function
    $(':focus').blur();

    // Prevent default
    event.preventDefault()

  }

});

/* Saves the edited cell data when user clicks outside the cell */
$(document).on('focusout', '.row_data', function(event) {

  // Prevent default
  event.preventDefault();

  // Check if NaN
  // Used .val() - not sure if you need to use .html in your use case
  if (isNaN($(this).val())) {

    // Notify user
    alert("Enter valid number")

  } else {

    // Pass element to save
    saveValue($(this))

  }

});


// Test saving function
function saveValue(elem) {

  // Send to console to prove it works
  console.log("Saving " + elem.val());

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input class="row_data">
```

Comment: Thanks very much, appreciate it. I'm just making some changes now. 

In my case I think ill need to use html because I'm just using a span attribute and making it editable through jquery.

Comment: Ah sure, then `.html` will be needed. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Hi having your HTML here will help suggest a better soultion, but the simple guess is that you are creating a loop, with your events.

You said the keypress event is the problem, just for testing purposes have you tried changing keypress to keydown/keyUp.

Also i sugges changing the alert to console.log, for easier debuging.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I've edited by post for more context. I had tried keydown but hadnt tried Key up. Another thing I've noticed, if I comment out the 'focus out' function the keypress function works perfectly too